# How do I transform and curve a square shape?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a square shape called receipt that rotates on it’s x axis when the user scrolls down the page. My goal is to curve the receipt as it transform and rotates on the x axis. Right know the square just rotates but need it to it to curve as it is rotating and then flatten out back to a square. I want the square to look like it is being printed from the page like an invoice machine here is an example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdO7NKzLdMY (watch at 1:12 mark).
I have tried playing with the different transform properties, but nothing seems to work. Can anyone help?

```js
/**
 * @type {HTMLDivElement}
 */
const invoice = document.querySelector(".receipt");

document.addEventListener(
  "scroll",
  (e) => {
    const posY = Math.min(window.scrollY, 300);

    // we end the rotation after scrolling 300px down the page.
    const rotationMaxScroll = 300;

    // this calculates the relative angle based on the scrolling position.
    const angle = (1 - posY / rotationMaxScroll) * 85;

    // the square will be out of view after scrolling 400px down the page.
    const translateMaxScroll = 400;

    // until we scroll past rotationMaxScroll - move the sqare on the range [-100%, 0%]
    // after we scroll past rotationMaxScroll - move the square down until out of view
    const translateY =
      window.scrollY > rotationMaxScroll
        ? `${
            ((window.scrollY - rotationMaxScroll) /
              (translateMaxScroll - rotationMaxScroll)) *
            250
          }px`
        : `${(1 - posY / rotationMaxScroll) * -100}%`;

    // apply position and rotation
    invoice.style.transform = `rotateX(${angle}deg) translateY(${translateY})`;
  },
  { passive: true }
);
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
section {
height: 100vh;
}

.one{
background-color: bisque;
}

.two{
  background-color: aqua;
}

.three{
  background-color: brown;
}
.parent{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 240px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 1000%, 0% 1000%);
}



.receipt {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: rotateX(85deg) translateY(-100%);
  transform-origin: top center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Revealing Invoice On Scroll</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

<body>
  <section class="one">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="wrapper">
    
        <div class="receipt"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="two"></section>
<section class="three"></section>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you use something [LIKE THIS](https://daily-dev-tips.com/posts/creating-a-3d-cylinder-shape-in-css/) to just create panels that give the illusion of the receipt curling over itself?